# copy last number of each line starting by specific character and append after that character

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a series of fasta files (text files with DNA sequence) like the `test.fna` file below

```
>NZ_LDZM01000028.1 Bacteria species strain bla1 contig_28, whole genome shotgun sequence_49
GGCGAAGAAACGGTCTAAATAGGCTGATTCAAGGCATTTACGGGAGAAAAAATCGGCTCAAACATGAAGAAATGAAATGACTGAGTCAGCCGAGAAGAATTTCCCCGCTTATTCGCACCTTCCCTAGAAACCTTTACCTGGCGAACGCAAATACAAGCGGGTTTGCAGGGGGATTTTAATTTCACCGTTCGCGAGGCTCGTTTTGGCGACGGATATCAGCAGATCGTCGGCGATGGTCTACATTTTGAAAAACAAAGCTGGCCAGTGACCTTGACCGGAGAAAAGGAAGAGATATTAGCCGTGCTTGAATTTATGCGGCGTCATGTAACGAAGTCGTTTATCTGGGATACCCCTGCGGGGGAATCCGGGCTTTATCGTGTTAGCGCCGATTCACTAAAACTTTCGCCATTATCGAGTCAAGTAATGACGGTAACCGCTACATTTAACCAGGCATATGCACCATGATTACAGCTGATTATCAAAAACTTGAACCCGGGAGT
>NZ_LDZM01000028.1 Bacteria species strain bla1 contig_28, whole genome shotgun sequence_50
ACGGCGCAGAAATTTAACGGCAGCAGGAGCCTGAGGCTGCGCCGTGAGGCGAATAACGGCGGCAACAGCGACAAGCAGATAGGGCCATGGTCGAGTATCCGCGAGAATGCCGTGTACAGTGTTGAGCTGTGGGCAATGATGCCGGCAGACCAGTCCCCGTCGACGGGCTGGCAGACGATAGTCGGCATTCAGGGTCAGAATGCGGCAGGGCAGAACAGTTGGCAGGGGGCGGTCACCATAACGGAAAGTGGCCTGGGCGAACGCGGGAAGTGGGTGAAATTCAGCGGCAAGGCGCGGATGAACGGAACCGGCAGGACGCGCGGTGTGGTATGGATTTCCACACGCGGAGCGACGGGTAGCGGAACGCCGGGTTACGATCTGTATATTGACGATATTGTCATCACAGATATAACCGATGCTCAGACAGCACTGGATGTAGCTGATGCCAGTACCACAGCTGTCAGCGGACTGACTACCCGCGTAACGAATGCTGAGACTAA
>NZ_LDZM01000029.1 KBacteria species strain bla1 contig_29, whole genome shotgun sequence_100
GGCGAAGAAACGGTCTAAATAGGCTGATTCAAGGCATTTACGGGAGAAAAAATCGGCTCAAACATGAAGAAATGAAATGACTGAGTCAGCCGAGAAGAATTTCCCCGCTTATTCGCACCTTCCCTAGAAACCTTTACCTGGCGAACGCAAATACAAGCGGGTTTGCAGGGGGATTTTAATTTCACCGTTCGCGAGGCTCGTTTTGGCGACGGATATCAGCAGATCGTCGGCGATGGTCTACATTTTGAAAAACAAAGCTGGCCAGTGACCTTGACCGGAGAAAAGGAAGAGATATTAGCCGTGCTTGAATTTATGCGGCGTCATGTAACGAAGTCGTTTATCTGGGATACCCCTGCGGGGGAATCCGGGCTTTATCGTGTTAGCGCCGATTCACTAAAACTTTCGCCATTATCGAGTCAAGTAATGACGGTAACCGCTACATTTAACCAGGCATATGCACCATGATTACAGCTGATTATCAAAAACTTGAACCCGGGAGT
>NZ_LDZM01000030.1 Bacteria species strain bla1 contig_30, whole genome shotgun sequence_999
ACGGCGCAGAAATTTAACGGCAGCAGGAGCCTGAGGCTGCGCCGTGAGGCGAATAACGGCGGCAACAGCGACAAGCAGATAGGGCCATGGTCGAGTATCCGCGAGAATGCCGTGTACAGTGTTGAGCTGTGGGCAATGATGCCGGCAGACCAGTCCCCGTCGACGGGCTGGCAGACGATAGTCGGCATTCAGGGTCAGAATGCGGCAGGGCAGAACAGTTGGCAGGGGGCGGTCACCATAACGGAAAGTGGCCTGGGCGAACGCGGGAAGTGGGTGAAATTCAGCGGCAAGGCGCGGATGAACGGAACCGGCAGGACGCGCGGTGTGGTATGGATTTCCACACGCGGAGCGACGGGTAGCGGAACGCCGGGTTACGATCTGTATATTGACGATATTGTCATCACAGATATAACCGATGCTCAGACAGCACTGGATGTAGCTGATGCCAGTACCACAGCTGTCAGCGGACTGACTACCCGCGTAACGAATGCTGAGACTAA
```

for each line starting by a `>`, I would like to copy the last number and place it after the `>`, thus returning:

```
>49NZ_LDZM01000028.1 Bacteria species strain bla1 contig_28, whole genome shotgun sequence_49
GGCGAAGAAACGGTCTAAATAGGCTGATTCAAGGCATTTACGGGAGAAAAAATCGGCTCAAACATGAAGAAATGAAATGACTGAGTCAGCCGAGAAGAATTTCCCCGCTTATTCGCACCTTCCCTAGAAACCTTTACCTGGCGAACGCAAATACAAGCGGGTTTGCAGGGGGATTTTAATTTCACCGTTCGCGAGGCTCGTTTTGGCGACGGATATCAGCAGATCGTCGGCGATGGTCTACATTTTGAAAAACAAAGCTGGCCAGTGACCTTGACCGGAGAAAAGGAAGAGATATTAGCCGTGCTTGAATTTATGCGGCGTCATGTAACGAAGTCGTTTATCTGGGATACCCCTGCGGGGGAATCCGGGCTTTATCGTGTTAGCGCCGATTCACTAAAACTTTCGCCATTATCGAGTCAAGTAATGACGGTAACCGCTACATTTAACCAGGCATATGCACCATGATTACAGCTGATTATCAAAAACTTGAACCCGGGAGT
>50NZ_LDZM01000028.1 Bacteria species strain bla1 contig_28, whole genome shotgun sequence_50
ACGGCGCAGAAATTTAACGGCAGCAGGAGCCTGAGGCTGCGCCGTGAGGCGAATAACGGCGGCAACAGCGACAAGCAGATAGGGCCATGGTCGAGTATCCGCGAGAATGCCGTGTACAGTGTTGAGCTGTGGGCAATGATGCCGGCAGACCAGTCCCCGTCGACGGGCTGGCAGACGATAGTCGGCATTCAGGGTCAGAATGCGGCAGGGCAGAACAGTTGGCAGGGGGCGGTCACCATAACGGAAAGTGGCCTGGGCGAACGCGGGAAGTGGGTGAAATTCAGCGGCAAGGCGCGGATGAACGGAACCGGCAGGACGCGCGGTGTGGTATGGATTTCCACACGCGGAGCGACGGGTAGCGGAACGCCGGGTTACGATCTGTATATTGACGATATTGTCATCACAGATATAACCGATGCTCAGACAGCACTGGATGTAGCTGATGCCAGTACCACAGCTGTCAGCGGACTGACTACCCGCGTAACGAATGCTGAGACTAA
>100NZ_LDZM01000029.1 KBacteria species strain bla1 contig_29, whole genome shotgun sequence_100
GGCGAAGAAACGGTCTAAATAGGCTGATTCAAGGCATTTACGGGAGAAAAAATCGGCTCAAACATGAAGAAATGAAATGACTGAGTCAGCCGAGAAGAATTTCCCCGCTTATTCGCACCTTCCCTAGAAACCTTTACCTGGCGAACGCAAATACAAGCGGGTTTGCAGGGGGATTTTAATTTCACCGTTCGCGAGGCTCGTTTTGGCGACGGATATCAGCAGATCGTCGGCGATGGTCTACATTTTGAAAAACAAAGCTGGCCAGTGACCTTGACCGGAGAAAAGGAAGAGATATTAGCCGTGCTTGAATTTATGCGGCGTCATGTAACGAAGTCGTTTATCTGGGATACCCCTGCGGGGGAATCCGGGCTTTATCGTGTTAGCGCCGATTCACTAAAACTTTCGCCATTATCGAGTCAAGTAATGACGGTAACCGCTACATTTAACCAGGCATATGCACCATGATTACAGCTGATTATCAAAAACTTGAACCCGGGAGT
>999NZ_LDZM01000030.1 Bacteria species strain bla1 contig_30, whole genome shotgun sequence_999
ACGGCGCAGAAATTTAACGGCAGCAGGAGCCTGAGGCTGCGCCGTGAGGCGAATAACGGCGGCAACAGCGACAAGCAGATAGGGCCATGGTCGAGTATCCGCGAGAATGCCGTGTACAGTGTTGAGCTGTGGGCAATGATGCCGGCAGACCAGTCCCCGTCGACGGGCTGGCAGACGATAGTCGGCATTCAGGGTCAGAATGCGGCAGGGCAGAACAGTTGGCAGGGGGCGGTCACCATAACGGAAAGTGGCCTGGGCGAACGCGGGAAGTGGGTGAAATTCAGCGGCAAGGCGCGGATGAACGGAACCGGCAGGACGCGCGGTGTGGTATGGATTTCCACACGCGGAGCGACGGGTAGCGGAACGCCGGGTTACGATCTGTATATTGACGATATTGTCATCACAGATATAACCGATGCTCAGACAGCACTGGATGTAGCTGATGCCAGTACCACAGCTGTCAGCGGACTGACTACCCGCGTAACGAATGCTGAGACTAA
```

Any ideas of how to do this, ideally with awk/sed would be great.

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in form of code which you have put in order to solve your own problem in your question and let us know then. Its highly encouraged on SO.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @RavinderSingh13, normally I would do that, but in this case I have not yet come up with useful code

Comment: Then its a kind request you to try something and add it in your question, cheers.

Comment: Use bash to move/rename/etc files, use `awk` to re-format data. [Awk Tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) . (This almost certainly a 1-liner in `awk`). We can only help fix your understanding of how things work if you include the code you have tried so far. People don't come here if they have the answer, so don't be bashful ;-) . Good luck!

Comment: You're trying to manipulate text. Doing that `directly in bash` would be a terrible idea since bash is a shell and shells aren't designed to manipulate text, they're designed to manipulate files and processes and sequence calls to tools (including tools that ARE designed to manipulate text, e.g. awk).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following `sed` command :

```
sed -E 's/^>(.*sequence_(.*))$/>\2\1/' test.fna
```

It matches line starting with `>` while capturing content into two capturing group :

- the first one starts after the `>` and goes up to the end of the line
- the second one starts after `sequence_` and goes up to the end of the line, capturing the number you want repeted at the start

It then replaces the lines matching by `>\2\1` where `\<n>` are references to the capturing groups : we reproduce the sequence number captured in group 2 just after the `>`, then add the rest of the line captured in group 1.

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/H50Kvj).

The command above will only output the modified text but not modify the original file. You can achieve that by using the `-i`n-place flag.

Answer (score 0):

One `awk` solution:

```
awk -F'_' '{ sub(/^>/,">"$(NF),$0) ; print }' dna.dat
```

Where:

- `-F'_'` - define input field separator as the underscore (`_`)
- `sub(/^>/,">"$(NF),$0)` - if the first character in the line is a right arrow (`>`), replace said character with a right arrow plus the last field in the line (`$(NF)`)
- `print` - print the (new) line to stdout